# Evaluate deviation from negative binomial model

Tags: r, regression, chi-squared-test, count-data, negative-binomial-distribution

I'm trying to figure out how to determine to what extent a sample deviates from a negative binomial model fitted to a larger population.

As an example, I generated counts of doctor visits for a population of males and females aged between 20 and 60:

```
library("MASS")
library("ggplot2")

set.seed(8)

n <- 1000
dispersion <- 1
baseline <- 1
ageeffect <- 0.02
gendereffect <- 0.5

gender <- sample(c("male", "female"), size=n, replace=TRUE)
age <- round(runif(n, min=20, max=60))
mu <- baseline + age * ageeffect + (gender=="female") * gendereffect
visits <- rnbinom(n, size=dispersion, mu=mu)
barplot(table(visits), space=0)

data <- data.frame(visits, gender, age)
summary(m <- glm.nb(visits ~ age + gender, data = data))

newdata <- data.frame(
  age = rep(seq(20, 60), 2),
  gender = c(rep("male", 41), rep("female", 41))
)

p <- predict(m, newdata, type="link", se.fit=TRUE)

newdata$visits <- exp(p$fit)
newdata$ll <- exp(p$fit - 1.96 * p$se.fit)
newdata$ul <- exp(p$fit + 1.96 * p$se.fit)

ggplot(newdata, aes(age, visits)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = ll, ymax = ul, fill = gender), alpha = .25) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = gender), size = 2) +
  labs(x = "Age", y = "Prediction")
```

Now I would like to quantify how much a specific group of people deviates from the model. Groups can be of different sizes and composition, and I'm only interested in groups which exhibit a above-normal number of doctor visits. The idea is to calculate some kind of scoring for each group (let's say the inhabitants of a specific neighbourhood) and follow this up over time.

What would be the preferred way of doing this? I did calculate p-values for each observation in the sample, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
samplesize <- 10
s <- data[sample(1:n, samplesize),]
pp <- predict(m, s, type="link", se.fit=TRUE)
s$mu <- as.vector(exp(pp$fit))
s$theta <- rep(m$theta, samplesize)
s$p <-  1 - pnbinom(s$visits, m$theta, mu=s$mu)
s

    visits gender age       mu     theta          p
487      0 female  48 2.385442 0.9899275 0.70307422
873      2 female  38 2.115261 0.9899275 0.31264813
19       3   male  29 1.440554 0.9899275 0.12164221
78       2 female  33 1.991872 0.9899275 0.29476639
362      1   male  43 1.704576 0.9899275 0.39648278
120      1 female  48 2.385442 0.9899275 0.49534441
658      1   male  53 1.922300 0.9899275 0.43182233
14       5 female  22 1.745163 0.9899275 0.06636807
663      2 female  57 2.657989 0.9899275 0.38294175
77       1   male  24 1.356523 0.9899275 0.33088457
```

**Edit 1:** After reading http://mikelove.wordpress.com/2012/03/12/combining-p-values-fishers-method-sum-of-p-values-binomial/, would Fisher's method be a good approach?

**Edit 2:** I'm exploring Pearson residuals now, but something's not clear to me. In the code below I generate a dataset and construct a model. I then calculate Pearson statistics for samples of 20 and 1000 counts. From what I read I expected these statistics to follow a Chi-squared distribution with n-2 degrees of freedom, but that doesn't  really seem to be the case. Am I doing something wrong?

```
library("MASS")

n <- 1000
dispersion <- 1
baseline <- 1
ageeffect <- 0.02
gendereffect <- 0.5

dataset <- function(n) {
  gender <- sample(c("male", "female"), size=n, replace=TRUE)
  age <- round(runif(n, min=20, max=60))
  mu <- baseline + age * ageeffect + (gender=="female") * gendereffect
  visits <- rnbinom(n, size=dispersion, mu=mu)
  data <- data.frame(visits, gender, age)
  return(data)  
}

model <- function(data) {
  m <- glm.nb(visits ~ age + gender, data = data)
}

pred <- function(data, m) {
  p <- predict(m, data, type="link", se.fit=TRUE)
  data$mu <- as.vector(exp(p$fit))
  data$theta <- rep(m$theta, length(data$visits))
  data$pr <- (data$visits - data$mu) / sqrt(data$mu + data$mu^2 / data$theta)
  return(data)
}

pearson.stat <- function(data) {
  return(sum(data$pr^2))
}

test.chisq <- function(data) {
  return(pchisq(pearson.stat(data), df = length(data$pr) - 2, lower=FALSE))
}

# population of 100000 and model

dp <- dataset(100000)
m <- model(dp)

# pearson statistic (samples of 1000)

ps <- NULL
for (i in seq(1, 1000)) {
  d <- dataset(1000)
  p <- pred(d, m)
  ps <- c(ps, pearson.stat(p))
}

# pearson statistic (samples of 20)

ps2 <- NULL
for (i in seq(1, 1000)) {
  d <- dataset(20)
  p <- pred(d, m)
  ps2 <- c(ps2, pearson.stat(p))
}

# plot

dplot <- function(res, df) {
  x <- seq(min(res), max(res), length.out=100)
  y <- dchisq(x, df=df)
  h <- hist(res, prob=T, breaks=30, main=paste(df, "degrees of freedom"), ylim=c(0, max(y)), xlab="Pearson statistic", ylab="density")
  lines(x, y, col="cornflowerblue", lwd=2)
}

par(mfrow=c(2, 1))
dplot(ps, df=1000-2)
dplot(ps2, df=20-2)
```

[image]

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using the standard Pearson or Deviance residuals?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on one of these, maybe with a code example? Thanks

Comment: Pearson and Deviance residuals are standard diagnostics for GLMs.  Pearson is easiest to define here as $r_i=\frac{y_i-\hat{\mu}_i}{\sqrt{var(y_i)}}=\frac{y_i-\hat{\mu}_i}{\sqrt{\hat{\mu}_i+\hat{\theta}^{-1}\hat{\mu}_i^2}}$.  In terms of R code this could be `pearson.resid <- (visits - m$fitted.values)/sqrt(m$fitted.values+m$fitted.values^2/m$theta)`.  This will give you residuals you can analyse for patterns, such as looking for "poorly fitting groups".

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into Pearson residuals now. See edit 2.